# How to add values to Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Sorry if this is a noob question but I am new to programming and python that is why I am asking.

I want to add values to my dictionary keys.

I have dictionary:

```
dictio = {"Object": "Computer"}
```

Now within the key **"Object"**, I would like to add the value **"Mouse"**.

So the end result i am looking for is:

```
>>> dictio
>>> {"Object": ["Computer", "Mouse"]}
```

Comment: Your dictionary in the result is invalid

Comment: @karthikr .. what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com)-ing it first before asking?

Comment: I mean The resulting dictionary should be something like `{"Object": ["Computer", "Mouse"]}` Try to initialize the dictionary with your resulting dictio, and you will know what i mean

Comment: oh yes that is what I meant.. the list.. sorry I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 4):

Your formulation seems to show you didn't grasp correctly what are *dict* in python. This also makes it difficult for us to understand what you want.

For instance:

```
I want to add values to my dictionary keys.
```

Is ambiguous (at least) and could be interpreted in several ways. I'll explain what is ambiguous in the following answer.

Even your original example was not helping, as it is not valid syntax:

```
>>> {"Object": "Computer", "Mouse"}
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The vocabulary of *dict* is about *key* and *values*.

In a *dict* every *key* has a *value* **and only one**.

So here's the question you'll have to answer: What is `"Mouse"` ? a *key* or a *value* of `dictio`, or none of them ?

Either you wanted:

```
>>> {"Object": "Computer", "Mouse": "A Sample Value"}
```

Which is a dictionary with a new pair of *key*/*value*. It can be done like this:

```
>>> dictio["Mouse"] = "A Sample Value"
```

Or perhaps you wanted to 'add' another *value* to the already stored *value* for the key `"Object"` in the dictionary. But 'adding' a *value* is ambiguous when speaking of a *value* in a *dict*, as dictionaries holds only one *value* for one *key* !

- Do you want the current *string* *value* to be concatenated with a new one ?
- Or do you want to replace the current *string* *value* with a *list* of *values* ? (If yes, your starting *value* should have been a *list* of one element in the first place).

The resulting *dict* using a *list* as *value* for the *key* `"Object"` would be:

```
>>> {"Object": ["My Computer", "Mouse"]}
```

So this would remain a one *key* *dict*, with one *value*. This *value* happens to be a *list* of *value*, it means that it self, it can hold several inner *values* in a specific order.

Notice that if I want to start from your original `dictio` to get the previous result, I have to replace the value `"Computer"` (of type *string*) with a different value of different type: `["My Computer", "Mouse"]` (it is a *list* of values).

So this could be done like this:

```
>>> dictio["Object"] = [dictio["Object"], "Mouse"]
```

But, this is not very natural and you would probably want to start with a `dictio` like this:

```
>>> dictio = {"Object": ["Mouse"]}
```

Then, 'adding' a *value* to a *list* is not anymore ambiguous. And then it would also be simpler to achieve:

```
 >>> dictio["Object"].append("Mouse")
```

I hope reading this helped you to better grasp what are *dicts* in python. You should probably find tutorials or basic docs about dictionaries as you seem to have missed some fundamental notions.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```
dictio = {"Object": ["Computer"]}

dictio["Object"].append("mouse")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a list operation on a string:

```
>>> 'string'.append('addition')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

You can only add something to the data structure if the addition is supported:

```
>>> li=['string']
>>> li.append('addition')
>>> li
['string', 'addition']
```

You want to take a dict composed of a string associated with another string:

```
dictio = {"Object": "Computer"}
```

And add to it as if it were a list. Same problem as above:

```
>>> dictio["Object"].append("Mouse")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What to do? If the object in the dict is a string, it needs to be a list to append to it.

You can test first:

```
>>> if isinstance(dictio["Object"], list): 
...    dictio["Object"].append('Mouse')
... else:
...    dictio["Object"]=[dictio["Object"]]
...    dictio["Object"].append('Mouse')
... 
>>> dictio
{'Object': ['Computer', 'Mouse']}
```

Or try it and react to failure:

```
try:
    dictio["Object"].append("Mouse")
except AttributeError:
    dictio["Object"]=[dictio["Object"]]
    dictio["Object"].append("Mouse")
```